# Who Do I Contact To Fix Exterior Water Damaged Wood

Tags: exterior, water-damage

[image: Front of my house where I assume Water runs down]

[image: More than one boards needs replaced]

Hopefully nothing behind the main damaged board, but I am sure there is a high possibility that there is. Master bedroom/Bathroom is directly behind this wall.

Comment: A siding or general contractor or a handyman.

Comment: That looks like exposed and painted OSB. The shingles above look to end in a channel that will hold water for them to absorb.  Who did that!!  The bottom row of shingles are probably compromised as well and who knows what damage is behind them.   This may be beyond most handymen.

Comment: OP, were those covered with aluminum fascia before or have they always been exposed like that?

Comment: I'd be more concerned with water getting behind the OSB and running down behind the siding or even inside the wall.

Comment: @RMDman, yeah exposed OSB, and all the water from the gable pouring down to that corner... that little trim strip needs to go!

Comment: Isn't the white piece at the top of the OSB - between the OSB and the (what looks like) a J-channel - some z-flashing?

Answer (score 1):

A roofing and/or siding contractor (roofing and siding are commonly done by the same company).  Anybody you call should be able to answer whether or not they'll fix it over the phone, regardless.

Comment: Took me a moment to realize that was "answer over the phone" rather than "fix it over the phone"... :-)